# Getting blackscreen sometimes when I switch activities that downloads images from web

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my android project, I notice a problem. When I click a button to go from activity `A` to `B`, I first run an async task, that downloads the information (I show a progress bar), and if I get the information, then I switch to `B`.

Then on the oncreate event of `B`, I try to download images using another async task.

However sometimes when I click the button to go to `B`, I see the progress bar of the async task that downloads the information as usual, but it appears that the spinning wheel is frozen, then I get a black screen. It does not do anything then, and if I click back, I can get back to activity `A`.

To fix this, I just reload the app into my phone using ADT (without changing the code at all), then it works again for a while.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: One Reason of that black screen may be there is too much of heavy code running in onCreate method Reduce that load and it will work fine.

Comment: do you mean oncreate method of activity `B`?

Comment: Yes onCreate of activity B

Comment: Just try to call your async in onResume method in Activity B

Comment: Does onResume event occur even if the activity just started? (like it was never started before)

Comment: Yes....in onResume() method set your view and call aysnc task in that...

Comment: do you mean `setContentView(R.layout....);` when you say set your view?

Comment: I tried it, but the problem still occurs.